# JVM unsupported version in CICS

Tags: for-loop, java, setting, cics

I am  getting The JVM specified is unsupported error while updating JVM path in IBM CICS.

Iam trying to update current CICS jvm path into c:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre\bin"\java.exe path.

command I used:

ctgjava -s=c:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre\bin"\java.exe

error:

JVM specified is unsupported

Any solution for this error?

Answer (score 1):

First -- you'll want to make sure that you've got the syntax correct in the ctgjava command:

```
ctgjava -s="c:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre\bin\java.exe"
```

You require the quotes around the path name because one of your directories has a space in it.

Secondly, check to make sure that the Java level you want to use (Java 7) is supported by the release of the CICS Transaction Gateway that you are running. For example, CICS TG v8.0 and v8.1 will only run with Java 6.

A great resource that I use for checking supported software levels with the CICS TG (on all platforms) is [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21239203) TechDoc from IBM.

Answer (score 0):

There is a weird quote in the middle of your path and another one is missing. Make sure the full path including `java.exe` is inside the qotes on Windows.

Comment: The quote is not the problem.actually while typing i missed to include the other one.

Comment: maybe update the question with your correct path, settings and complete error message?